# How to send cookies from vuejs to lumen

Tags: vue.js, cookies

I develop a vuejs SPA and I need to communicate with an API (develop with lumen). Firstly user indicate email and password and send post request to back end (I use axios). Backend response set cookies with the jwt value, and I need to send on every request this cookies. My problem is when I post login information I get good response with cookies but if send a new request the cookies is no send and I don't view cookies in web developper on chrome.

```js
let credential = {
    email: data.email,
    password: data.password,
};

axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login", credential, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    withCredentials: true
})
    .then(user => {
        console.log(user.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

My front and back are on different domain. And I modify cors already.

Comment: try axios param ``crossDomain: true``

Comment: Same issue with that